# Can connect to other wireless networks but not my home wireless network

Tags: wireless

This all started when I brought down my computer to my living room, and connected it via ethernet. It can detect it but not connect. Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

First, reboot you system and see if it becomes normal.
If not so, completely revome your wifi network configurations. After that try to reconnect to it.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove network connections"?

Comment: I said "network configurations". It's to remove any *configuration* of you home wifi from you computer. Are you using Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: Linux. I'm using Ubuntu

Comment: You've got your computer connected to your wifi?

Comment: No. Not now and I can't